# Is Zero less than or equal to zero?

Tags: c, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

Assume I get a value `i=0;`
Then will the following variable `leftsmaller` be `true`?

```
 while(i<=0 || arr[i]<arr[j])
    leftsmaller = true;
```

Comment: 0 < 0 evaluates to false, however 0 = 0 so 0 <= 0 is true

Comment: Why didn't you just try the code out with `i = 0` above it?

Comment: @Quill-HATMANIAC Just trying out things you're not sure about, may invoke UB, so you can't be sure if other compilers do the same thing.

Comment: @Monty By the way, do you realise that since none of the variables in the condition change values, the loop will never end if i<=0 to begin with?

Comment: What? even `0 == -0` is true.

Comment: @iharob not necessarily, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

No zero is not less then zero, `i <= 0` becomes `1` because zero is less than **or equal to** zero.

Answer (score 2):

The `<=` ("less than or equal") operator returns `true` if the left hand side is less than **or equal** to the right hand side. Since `0` is, of course, equal to `0`, so this expression will evaluate to `true`, which will cause the code enter the `while` loop, assigning `true` to `leftsmaller`.

Answer (score 2):

Of course zero isn't less than zero, but `i <= 0` becomes `1` because zero is *less than or equal to* zero.

Answer (score 1):

The variable type of `i` is never mentioned.

If it is `unsigned i` then the `< 0` part of the test will fail.

If it is `float i` then the `== 0` part of the test can fail - even when you could swear that `i` should be `0`, since inexact values can be stored.

Comment: While this is technically correct, a test `i==0` is always true after an `i = 0;`  assignment, even with float variables.